# Automatically parse the body?

Tags: go

Is there any way to parse the body of the request automatically, instead of doing this `if` in each handler!

I'm using the go-fiber framework

```golang
if err := c.BodyParser(&post); err != nil {
    // do something
}
```

I've heard that some people don't recommend this but I'm curious why!

Comment: Because parsing can fail. There are no exceptions in GO and  error is the only way to know that data in `post` can be trusted.

Comment: @RedBlue How can I parse the body of the request automatically instead of doing parse each time in the handler

Comment: @DmitryHarnitski Thanks. But Can I create a middleware for parsing the body? Or this is also not recommended!

Comment: I prefer vanilla GO. If you like frameworks/middlewares, try `https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin` It includes JSON parsing.

Comment: Assuming that each handler uses a unique type for `post`, you would need a way for the middleware to discover that type.

Comment: @RedBlue mostly my apps r an API projects

Comment: @kepemo2494 though unconventional you can avoid the repetitiveness of "common logic" in handlers by declaring a custom interface, a base type that implements most of its methods, and then have the individual handler types embed the base type. https://go.dev/play/p/YggpBEAyBUw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a middleware, use a method like this one:

```golang
const PostKey = "post"

func CreateBodyParsingMiddleware(handler func(*fiber.Ctx) error) func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    return func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        var post Post //type Post is declared elsewhere
        if err := c.BodyParser(&post); err != nil {
            return fiber.NewError(fiber.StatusBadRequest, "invalid body")
        }
        c.Locals(PostKey, post)
        err := handler(c)
        return err
    }
}
```

Use the middleware with something like

```golang
router.Get("/", CreateBodyParsingMiddleware(myRequestHandler))
```

You can now access the post with `c.Locals(PostKey)` in `myRequestHandler`.

Comment: That is mean for each model I have to create a middleware for parsing the data, Right?

Comment: Well, you either pass the expected target type/variable as argument for `CreateBodyParsingMiddleware` which would help you to re-use the code. Or you could try to parse the data in different ways one after another, or you can use another information about the target type, e.g. from the request url or the request body so you don't have to go through all of them.

Comment: The more I think about it: I'ld say pass `targetVariable interface{}, keyToStoreData string` right next to the handler, and then register the different created middlewares to different endpoints. And make sure it It's hard to provide you any solid recommendations though, as I don't really know your use case.